# Can I show input max length alert in chrome like IE

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I setted maxlength like `<input type="text" maxlength="10">`

I loaded value from api then set this value at input element. And then click submit button.

I can check alert message for maxlength in IE 11 (I don't know other version).

But, Chrome doesn't show me this alert.

Chrome show me other alert. for example `require`

I can what to do about Chrome show me maxlength alert.

Sorry about my short english.

Answer (score 0):

You could acheive this by using jQuery. Please find the following code below.

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

{

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {

   var maxlength = $("input[type='text']").attr('maxlength');

   alert(maxlength);

 });
```

});

Comment: uhhhh.. I don't want to javascript alert window.
Can I get input form valid alert?

Comment: You could acheive this by adding title tag in the text box. <input type="text" maxlength="10" title="Maxlength 10">. when you hover the field it will show the maxlength value. or you will open the title attribute when you submit.

Comment: You run my jsfiddle in chrome? You can see this alert message?
I still can't see it.
And I want auto focus alert message like required. don't want hover message.

https://jsfiddle.net/ps8pzz0r/4

Comment: you could acheive this exactly by using this code   <input id="UserID"  type="text" required="required"
       oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Maxlength:10')">

Answer (score 0):

you could acheive this exactly by using this code

```
<input id="UserID" type="text" required="required" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Maxlength:10')">
```